# Variable suddenly changing - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My app uses a custom xml file that is frequently accessed. It rarely changes, so I want to cache the value to speed things up. This worked before, but now it doesn't. I changed from using 1 variable, to a hash variable ++, but I cannot see why that shouldn't work. Suddenly a foreign value is placed in the variable without me doing any updates... where does this value suddenly come from? I have no other places in the code setting this variable except in the code below. yes, I could use Rails caching, but I wanted this plain and simple, also for dev env. If I enable the "clear_cache" and skip the cache - the code works fine but slow.

```
   #Returns a file config in Ruby format. Using Cache variable
  def config_rb
    #clear_cache
    if @config and @config[collection_id]
      puts "..Cache contains: " + @config[collection_id]["root"]["searches"]["search"][4]["tables"]["table"][2]["fields"]  
      return @config[collection_id]
    else #get from file
      puts "..Updating cache for collection " + collection_id
      @config ||= {} 
      file = get_config.read
      begin
        if is_xml? file
          @config[collection_id] = Hash.from_xml file
        else 
          puts "Using JSON parser"
          raise "Not implemented"
          @config[collection_id] = JSON.parse file
        end
      rescue => e
        logger.debug e.cause
      end
    end
  end

..Updating cache for collection 06adfff0-0ddf9-4065-948a-286adfd2714
..Cache contains: ENHET,AVDELNING,PLACEMENTID
..Cache contains: ENHET,AVDELNING,PLACEMENTID
..Cache contains: ENHET,AVDELNING,PLACEMENTID
..Cache contains: ENHET,AVDELNING,PLACEMENTID
..Cache contains: ENHET,AVDELNING,PLACEMENTID
..Cache contains: ENHET,AVDELNING,PLACEMENTID
..Cache contains: ENHET,AVDELNING,PLACEMENTID
..Cache contains: ENHET,AVDELNING,PLACEMENTID
..Cache contains: ENHET,AVDELNING,PLACEMENTID
..Cache contains: ENHET,AVDELNING,PLACEMENTID
..Cache contains: ENHET,AVDELNING,PLACEMENTID,PERSONID
..Cache contains: ENHET,AVDELNING,PLACEMENTID,PERSONID
..Cache contains: ENHET,AVDELNING,PLACEMENTID,PERSONID
..Cache contains: ENHET,AVDELNING,PLACEMENTID,PERSONID
..Cache contains: ENHET,AVDELNING,PLACEMENTID,PERSONID
..Cache contains: ENHET,AVDELNING,PLACEMENTID,PERSONID
```

Update:
This simpler scenario does not work either, only when enabling the first line:

```
  #Returns the file config in Ruby format. Using Global Cache.
  def config_rb
    #@config = nil
    @config ||= Hash.from_xml get_config.read
  end
```

Comment: Nice nickname :) that line is a little bit cryptic...but the file is read once. If not I would get a new line saying "Updating cache" in the log.

Comment: Have you searched your code for `PERSONID` yet to see where it might be getting injected into your hash?

Comment: Actually I am injecting the  primary key like this: fl << + "," + pk  at a later stage.  But not involving this @config variable. Unless there are some different named objects sharing the same object_id... But how can that happen...

Comment: Actually its the code above that shares a subpart of the global variable. The object id is different.  I have several nested functions connecting to different levels of the config Problem introduced here I think. Tried dup/clone so far ..
  def get_search_config(si)
    raise "Argument cannot be nil" if si.nil?
    config = config_rb["root"]["searches"]["search"]
    case config
    when Hash #just one search in config
      config
    when Array #multiple searches in config
      config[si]
    else
      puts "Unknown scenario for this class: " + config.class
    end
  end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that config_rb returns a direct reference to the Cache variable @config. I have many nested functions to extract small parts of the config e.g.

```
fl = get_table_config(si,ti)["fields"] rescue nil
fl << ",PERSONID" # Big problem! Unless there has been a deep copy somewhere in the chain
```

But each and every small function in the chain share memory with the cache variable!

This is the solution, found in another thread. This makes a deep copy of the object. I may move this part further up in the chain to save some speed, but as for now it will stay close to the root to avoid other surprises.

```
  def deep_copy(obj)
    Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(obj))
  end

  #Returns a file config in Ruby format. Using Cache variable.
  def config_rb
    if @config and @config[collection_id]
      c = @config[collection_id]
    else #get from file
      @config ||= {} 
      file = get_config.read
      begin
        if is_xml? file
          c = @config[collection_id] = Hash.from_xml file
        elsif is_json? file
          c = @config[collection_id] = JSON.parse file
        end
      rescue => e
        logger.debug e.cause
      end
    end
    deep_copy(c) #Important! Or fl << pk will modify the cache!
  end
```

btw 1: I tried to make this variable global (yes, thats even more dangerous), but that did not give any speed benefit, so staying safer with a class variable. Your comments helped a lot, thanks!

btw 2: I did try clone and dup, but that did not work.